# functions, images, preimages and their respective algebras

Tags: functions

Please can you help me to prove that:

$$f^{-1}\left( f \left( f ^{-1} \left(f(A) \right) \right) \right) = f ^{-1}(f(A))$$

where $A \subseteq X$ and $f(A)$ is the image of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that for any subset $A\subseteq X$ and any function $f:X\to Y$, we must have that
$$f(f^{-1}(f(A)))=f(A).$$
You will want to use the fact that for any $y\in f(A)$, there is an element $x\in A$ such that $f(x)=y$ (that is, that $f^{-1}(y)$ is not empty).

Since $f(f^{-1}(f(A)))=f(A)$, we clearly have that 
$$f^{-1}\left( f \left( f ^{-1} \left(f(A) \right) \right) \right) = f ^{-1}(f(A)).$$

Comment: your answer was very helpful.thank you very much.